# When is an affine left cell finite?

Tags: co.combinatorics, coxeter-groups, weyl-group, affine-hecke-algebras

Consider an affine Weyl group $\hat W$ of a simple Lie type. Let $w \in \hat W$ and let $C^L(w)$ denote the left cell in $\hat W$ containing $w$.

Is there a good criterion to test whether $C^L(w)$ has finitely many elements? Preferably the criterion can be tested on the element $w$ itself.

Thanks in advance!